# Adding an image field while creating a suitelet List in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Basically I am creating a suitelet of type List. 
But I need to append a image/icon in that column.

1. what should be the column field type.
2. I tried with inlne html but it throws error that it doesn't exist
3. I tried image. though it doesn't throw error but I am not sure how to initialize it.

   ```
    function CustomSalesOrderListPending(request, response) {
     try {
       var list = nlapiCreateList('ItemsPendingList');
       //list.setStyle("grid");
       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'List Created ');
       list.addColumn('item_ship_date', 'date', 'Ship Date', 'left');
       var column = list.addColumn('number', 'text', 'SO#', 'left');

       list.addColumn('item_description', 'text', 'Style', 'left');
       list.addColumn('item_quantity', 'text', 'Quantity', 'left');

        var lamList = list.addColumn('item_lam','image','Lam', 'left');
        // add the url of the image
        var img = "https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1028824&c=888808&h=f3f288eaa19e2b084dd3";

       // list.addColumn('lam', 'image', 'Lam', 'left');
       // list.addColumn('dc', 'image', 'D/C', 'left');
       // list.addColumn('print', 'image', 'Print', 'left');
       // list.addColumn('assembly', 'image', 'Assembly', 'right');

       nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Search Created ');
       var result = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder','customsearch_sales_order_ship_date');

       if (result != null)
       {
           resultColumns = result[0].getAllColumns();  

           nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'List result ',result.length);
           for(var x=0; x<result.length; x++)
           {
               var searchresult = result[x];
               if (searchresult.getValue(resultColumns[2]) != '')
               {
                   var shipDate = searchresult.getValue(resultColumns[0]);   //--Ship Date
                   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'shipDate',shipDate);
                   var salesOrder = searchresult.getValue(resultColumns[1]);   //--Sales Order
                   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'salesOrder',salesOrder);
                   var description = searchresult.getValue(resultColumns[2]);   //--Description
                   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'description',description);
                   var quantity = searchresult.getValue(resultColumns[3]);   //--Quantity
                   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'quantity',quantity);

                   var res = new Object(); 
                   res['item_ship_date'] = shipDate ;
                   res['number'] = salesOrder;
                   res['item_description'] = description;
                   res['item_quantity'] = quantity;
                   res['lamList'] = img;
                   list.addRow(res);
                   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'list Added',x);
               }
           }
       }

   response.writePage(list);
   }

   catch(ex) {
   nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Error in CustomSalesOrderListPending: ', ex);
   }
   ```

This is the code I am using. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CustomSalesOrderListPending(request, response) {

        var list = nlapiCreateList('ItemsPendingList');
        //list.setStyle("grid");

        list.addColumn('item_ship_date', 'text', 'Ship Date', 'left');
        var column = list.addColumn('number', 'text', 'SO#', 'left');

        list.addColumn('item_description', 'text', 'Style', 'left');
        list.addColumn('item_quantity', 'text', 'Quantity', 'left');

         var lamList = list.addColumn('item_lam','text','Lam', 'left');
         var img = "https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1028824&c=888808&h=f3f288eaa19e2b084dd3";

         var res = new Object(); 
         res['item_ship_date'] = '33333' ;
         res['number'] = '4444';
         res['item_description'] = 'desc';
         res['item_quantity'] = '22';
         res['item_lam'] =  '<img src='+img+'>';;
         list.addRow(res);

         response.writePage(list);
    }
```